# Titanium: Enable button if textfield is not empty

Tags: events, button, titanium, textfield, titanium-alloy

Is their such a way that a button will automatically be enabled if two or more specific textfields have values e.g. listen for a change in a couple of textfields and enable button once they have values

Any help towards this problem would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using Alloy and in view you have proper objects with ids.
`textfields` it's just simple array with references to all TextFields in view, so it's easier to attach event listener for all of them and check if every single one is empty. You can always reverse this condition and make your button visible only if all of them has value.

```
var textfields = [$.textfield01, $.textfield02]

function checkTextfield(event) {
    if (this.value !== '') {
        $.button.visible = true;
    } else {
        for (var i in textfields) {
            if (textfields[i].value !== '') {
                return;
            }
        }
        $.button.visible = false;
    }
}

for (var i in textfields) {
    textfields[i].addEventListener('change', checkTextfield);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time! I have something similar to this but I am also dealing with dynamic fields being adde by the user.

Comment: If you need more help, you need to present some example code.

Comment: Finally got it working, marked as answer as your solution gave me another POV :)